How to get Http Client Interface to return ResponseEntity even when there is a client 40X or 50X error
Given a simple method such as
  @GetExchange("/foo")
  Mono<ResponseEntity<List<Foo>>> getFoos();

in FooInterface, with a 'standard' WebClient backing it.
The factory is also 'generic':
    HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
      .builderFor(WebClientAdapter.create(webClient))
      .build();

    return factory.createClient(FooInterface.class);

When the client is used and a 40X or 50X response occurs, then the WebClient throws a WebClientResponseException - which is unexpected - as I would think that having specified Mono<ResponseEntity<List<Foo>>> as the return type would have returned a ResponseEntity with status 40X or 50X.
The factory seems to prefer a retrieve rather than an exchange despite the annotation being GetExchange.
I haven't found a way to influence this behavior through configuration.  It seems like a bug.  I can change my code to respond to the exception and remap it to a ResponseEntity, but this seems strange to me.
I'm just starting to look at the Spring Web code for insight, but thought I'd throw it out to the experts.  Is anyone familiar with how to set this up?

Maybe the documentation will help? https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

This question is similar to: How to respond with an HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is specifically about the response returned by HTTP Interface clients when a client error occurs. Not about error handling for web clients generally. Given the “direction” provided to the factory to return a ResponseEntity, like what you would get using ‘exchange’, the behavior is more like using ‘retrieve’ where an exception is thrown for an error - yet ResponseEntity is returned otherwise. Seems inconsistent to me. Thanks for the response and I hope this makes my intent clearer.

Both the documentation and one of the answers mentions the usage of ControllerAdvice which you can use to handle any error including 40x/50x, for instance, for a 404 in a controller advice annotated class you can add a method to handle it @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class) or you can implement a customer error handler through ErrorController overriding the error default endpoint @RequestMapping("/error") and returning whatever you need for the specific error.

Yes. I know that I can handle errors in many ways. I am specifically looking for a way to coerce HTTP Interface clients to produce a response that is consistent with the declared return type.

After consulting with the Spring team, I've found that raising an exception is the only way to deal with 40X or 50X errors using HTTP Client Interfaces. You can customize the exception as described in Error Handling, but you cannot return a client response.  This is by design and will not be enhanced. Fortunately, Spring and Spring Boot provide many ways to work with errors.
